# PHP(SQL) Script using GROUP by does not display some fields correctly

Tags: php, sql

I am reasonably new to PHP but have been stuck on this for days. Basically, I have a fishing website that has two databases. One is for personal bests and one for all time records. Now, I thought it would be simpler to have just the one table, with everyones personal best and then I could use a PHP/SQL script to retrieve the all time records.

Problem is, it retrieves the name of the fish and and highest weight caught but yet always displays the one person, not the correct person who caught it.

Table consists of the fields basically like Species, FishName, Rank, Weight (Drams), Angler, Peg, DateCaught.

The SCRIPT is

```
$query = "SELECT Type, Name, Rank, Person, MAX(Drams) as Drams FROM table GROUP BY Name  ORDER BY Type ASC, Rank ASC"; 

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
echo "<b>Testing a display of All Time Records from PB Table.</b> <br>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo "Records for ". $row['Type']. " with name ". $row['Name']. " weighs ". $row['Drams']. " caught by ". $row['Person'];
echo "<br>";
}
mysql_close($con);
```

What should happen is a list will now produce showing each Name for a fish and the weight that they were caught, and who caught it as in Example 1 but example 2 is happening instead.

Example 1:

Records for Carp with name Piggy weighs 1024 caught  by David Bloggs

Carp with name Flipper weighs 123 caught by Arthur Smith

Example 2:

Records for Carp with name Piggy weighs 1024 caught  by David Bloggs

Carp with name Flipper weighs 123 caught by Arthur Smith

Comment: Be aware that the `mysql_xxx()` functions are considered obsolete and insecure. It is recommended to use the `mysqli_xx()` functions instead or the PDO library. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-function-in-php

Comment: Example 1 & Example 2 are the same. Can you edit Example 1 with your desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you are getting the correct `MAX(Drams)`, but that on the `GROUP BY Name` you are getting the 1st `Person` data not the `Person` that has the `MAX(Drams)`

Here are 2 different ways to accomplish what you are trying to do-

---

This first one has a `nestled` `SELECT` that reorders your rows by `Name - ASC` and `Drams - DESC`, with the outside doing the `GROUP BY Name` to get the top record

```
SELECT Type, Name, Rank, Person, Drams 
FROM (SELECT Type, Name, Rank, Person, Drams FROM table ORDER BY Name, Drams DESC) a
GROUP BY Name 
ORDER BY Type ASC, Rank ASC
```

**Here is how this one works-**
1- The nestled `SELECT` runs first, and reorders the table rows by Name (A-Z) and Drams (High-Low). This organized table is then temporarily stored as table `a`.

```
(SELECT Type, Name, Rank, Person, Drams FROM table ORDER BY Name, Drams DESC) a
```

2- The outside `SELECT` now take table `a`, and executes the `GROUP BY Name`, giving us the first (or top/highest) record for each Fish Name, and orders the results by Type (A-Z) and Rank (Low-High).

```
SELECT Type, Name, Rank, Person, Drams 
FROM  a  /* table a was set in step 1 */
GROUP BY Name 
ORDER BY Type ASC, Rank ASC
```

---

The second one has a `nestled` `SELECT` that gets the `MAX(Drams)`, and then `JOIN`s it to the row with the top record

```
SELECT table.Type, table.Name, table.Rank, table.Person, table.Drams
FROM table
JOIN ( SELECT Name, MAX(Drams) AS Drams FROM table GROUP BY Name) maxDrams
ON table.Name = maxDrams.Name 
AND table.Drams = maxDrams.Drams
ORDER BY Type ASC, Rank ASC
```

**Here is how this one works-**
1- The nestled `SELECT` runs first, and selects each Fish Name (via the `GROUP BY Name`) and its MAX(Drams). This organized table is then temporarily stored as table `maxDrams`.

```
(SELECT Name, MAX(Drams) AS Drams FROM table GROUP BY Name) maxDrams
```

2- The outside `SELECT` now take table `maxDrams`, and does a `JOIN` with the original table - `table`. It finds the row(s) in `table` that has `Name` and `Drams` that `==` as the rows in `maxDrams`, and orders the results by Type (A-Z) and Rank (Low-High).

```
SELECT table.Type, table.Name, table.Rank, table.Person, table.Drams
FROM table
JOIN maxDrams  /* table maxDrams was set in step 1 */
ON table.Name = maxDrams.Name 
AND table.Drams = maxDrams.Drams
ORDER BY Type ASC, Rank ASC
```

---

You can see an example at - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b6b66/7. This shows both examples with the `nestled` querys executed first, and then the whole querys executed. Hope this makes it a little clearer.

Comment: Thank you Sean. The first one worked perfectly. Could not get the second to work - message being something like tables derived etc... Do you mind explaining to me how this code works? Which part is actioned first, the brackets or the start?

Comment: I have added some explanations for each query, and linked to a sqlfiddle that shows examples of both queries. [http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b6b66/7](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b6b66/7). Hope this helps.